# Adobe CS4 nearly useless under Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, adobe-cs4

So, my girlfriend is a graphic designer, and uses Adobe's CS4 suite daily.  She upgraded to Snow Leopard, and now it takes about a minute-a-megabyte to save an image to disk.  It's painful to watch, and she's going a bit insane with this.  The computer is a year-old iMac.

Adobe is "looking into it", and seems to want Apple to patch this.  Apple seems to want Adobe to patch this.

Is there any way to go to Leopard from Snow Leopard if Time Machine wasn't enabled when the original update was applied?  Is there anyway to install the OS from scratch without losing everything else on the computer?

*Edit:*

So, the problem seems to be documented by Adobe [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2009/09/a_few_problems_found_with_ps_sl.html), in that *A bug can cause Photoshop & other applications to crash, particularly during Open and Save operations.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I upgraded from leopard to snow leopard. I completely removed CS4 using the Uninstaller located at /Applications/Utilities/Adobe\ Installers/Adobe Creative Suite 4... (**do not drag and drop to Trash**) Reboot. Reinstall all required packages. I only experience a crash issue when I close Photoshop.

To answer some of your questions:

> Is there any way to go to Leopard from Snow Leopard if Time Machine wasn't enabled when the original update was applied?

Simple answer is no. If you have no previous backups of leopard you cannot put the leopard disc and overwrite the snow leopard install.

I had a timemachine backup of leopard, and I have tried restoring leopard from snow leopard in a virtual environment and some of the hidden system files do not get moved properly and remain as the OS 10.6.x updates.

> Is there anyway to install the OS from scratch without losing everything else on the computer?

If you have all your important files/documents backed up, a leopard disc, software to re-install, and a Saturday afternoon. You can install from scratch. If you want to install overtop of snow leopard, no go!